# Compare undefined/null/NaN with number in ActionScript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, null, undefined

In ActionScript 1 and 2, if you compare `undefined`, `null` or `NaN` with an arbitrary number using `>=` or `<=` operator, the result is always `true`. Test code:

```
var x, n, range = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            x = undefined;
            break;
        case 1:
            x = null;
            break;
        case 2:
            x = NaN;
            break;
    }
    n = range*Math.random();
    trace(x + ' >= ' + n + ': ' + (x >= n));
    n = range*Math.random();
    trace(x + ' <= ' + n + ': ' + (x <= n));
}
```

Furthermore, `isNaN(null)` return `true`.

These are contrary to JavaScript and may not conform with ECMA standard.

Are these **bugs** or **intention**?

Thanks!

Comment: isNaN(null) should return true, since it's not a number... Did not notice these other corner cases, but being that those are "illegal" or better explained as undefined results of operations I'm relatively sure it's intentional. You are not supposed to do some things like a == NaN so you have to use isNaN() to test for that... My guess would be that operators can't throw exceptions in AS so they had to resort to that but I'm far from an expert on ActionScript internals...

Comment: If it's intentional, why the result when using `<` or `>` operator is `false`?

Comment: The result for `>`or `<`should always be `undefined` - I tested that. I'm a bit surprised that you could get `false`.

Comment: @weltraumpirat, Sorry, I'm wrong, the result for `>` or `<` is `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Since ActionScript 2 knows only one numerical type, Number, all the non-numerical elements in your comparisons are cast to Number - which would be the same as writing:

```
Number (null) <= n
Number (undefined) <= n
Number (NaN) <= n
```

`Number (`{anything but a number}`)` always returns NaN, therefore all your statements really only compare random Numbers with NaN. The ActionScript documentation clearly warns about NaN not being comparable, and advises to always use isNaN() to test for it.

If you *do* compare with NaN, however, it is a strange thing in AS2:

```
NaN == Number // returns false
NaN != Number // returns true
```

These behave as expected, but:

```
NaN >= Number // returns true
NaN <= Number // returns true
```

and finally:

```
NaN > Number // returns undefined
NaN < Number // returns undefined
```

Of course that is not very intuitive - any comparison with NaN should always be false, and that has been fixed in AS 3 - but it makes absolute sense that `null` is not a Number, and hence `isNaN(null)` *should* return `true`.

Comment: Ok, so the comparison result is buggy but don't know why Adobe doesn't fix it. In case of `null`, I like the way JavaScript considers it as `0`, not `NaN` as in ActionScript.

Comment: It's not buggy if the behavior was never intended.  And it has predictable behavior in AS3.  Just move on, as the rest of us have since 2006 :)

Comment: Sometimes you can't do what you want:(. I'm using [Ming](http://www.libming.org) to generate SWF files but it doesn't support AS3.